# Error Converting String to JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, parsing

Need help on android. Been having this error `Error Parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

Below is the page that is giving me the error when i run it.

```
public class Login extends Activity {

//URL to get User Data
private static String URL_GET = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_authentication.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_USERS = "Users";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "Email";
private static final String TAG_PASSWORD = "Password";

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
String dbPassword = null;
// users JSONArray
JSONArray Users = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setting default screen to login.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);


    // Listening to register new account link
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String password =  ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.password)).getText().toString();
            new getAuthentication().execute();

            if (password.equals(dbPassword)) {
                // Switching to Main screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EchoSphere.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
class getAuthentication extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;

                try {
                    String email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();

                    Log.d("email:", email);

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_EMAIL, email));

                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_GET, "GET", params);
                    Log.d("Password:", json.toString());

                     success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);       

                    if (success == 1) {
                        Users = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USERS);
                        JSONObject c = Users.getJSONObject(0);
                        dbPassword = c.getString(TAG_PASSWORD);
                        Log.d("DBPW:", dbPassword);
                    }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    }

                });
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

This is the PHP script, i've validated the PHP and it shows to be working.

```
<?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["Email"])) {
$email = $_GET['Email'];

// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Email, Password FROM Users WHERE Email = '$email'");

if (!empty($result)) {
    // check for empty result
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $user[] = array();
        $user["Email"] = $result["Email"];
        $user["Password"] = $result["Password"];

        // user node
        $response["Users"] = array();

        array_push($response["Users"], $user);

        // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No User found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // no product found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No User found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {

// required field is missing

$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The results is as shown

```
{"Users":[{"0":[],"Email":"1","Password":"123"}],"success":1}
```

I do not know where the error lies at.

Comment: If you view the source/print out the result of http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_authentication.php, is there anything else there besides the JSON?

Comment: nothing else appears apart from the JSON just the result

Comment: the response from the server is an html error page i think, that is why you are getting json parse error

Comment: When i run the page, my logcat shows the email. i got a feeling the error happens at JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_GET, "GET", params); as the logcat does not show the password retrieved

Comment: The error is in the PHP or server setup. I think @thujeevan's suggestion of an HTML error page is the most likely answer, have a look in the server access/error logs to see what the server is actually returning when it receives the request and whether there are any useful error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the error.

Thank you all for helping.

I added

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

to the php script and the application can run.